# pandas DataFrame column not showing on df.columns

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I'm wondering how to get the Date column values. The 'Date' column doesn't show when typing df.columns. I'm trying to get this df into a Json file with df.to_json(), which get all values but the Date. Thank you all.

```
             Open   High    Low  Close
Date
2020-03-16  36.01  41.40  36.01  39.04
2020-03-17  40.50  43.57  39.11  41.51
2020-03-18  38.80  40.87  35.70  38.65
2020-03-19  37.50  39.00  35.26  36.40
2020-03-20  37.90  39.41  34.71  35.19
```

In [49]: type(df)
Out[49]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

Answer (score 11):

Looks like `Date` is currently in the index. If you would like it to be a column, you just have to reset the index:

```py
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know I could have values on the index. You were really helpful! :)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear because it's not really a column, it's the index. It shouldn't matter, however, because by default, `df.to_json()` will by default include the index. It says so in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html).

Comment: Thank you! Some how it's not including. But if I reset_index like @kgoettler said above it worked! :)